# Php sql ORDER BY --

Tags: php, sql

Users Table:

```
ID|Name|Deleted
1 |    |  N 
2 | b  |  Y 
3 | c  |  N
4 | d  |  N
```

Deleted default value is 'N'

I want to order by id desc but I want to display deleted user last.

i.e. when Deleted 'Y' should appear last

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use multiple keys in `order by`.  So:

```
order by (deleted = 'Y') asc, id desc
```

The expression `(deleted = 'Y')` is a boolean expression that MySQL treats as a number with 1 for true and 0 for false.  The `asc` puts the true values last.

In most other databases, you would do this with a `case`:

```
order by (case when deleted = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end) desc, id desc
```

Comment: would it be possible to also just do `ORDER BY deleted, id DESC` (or `ORDER BY deleted ASC, id DESC`) since the values `N/Y` are alphabetic order?

Comment: @Sean . . . Yes, that is also possible.  I tend to be cautious, just in case there could be other values.

Comment: THANKS a lot people.

Comment: The `(deleted = 'Y')` version also works well any ANSI SQL compliant dbms that supports boolean. If `deleted = 'Y'`, then `TRUE` is returned, else `FALSE`. And `FALSE` is ordered before `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the simple solution

```
select * from table_name ORDER BY deleted ASC, id DESC
```